# How does React class component method's parameters work?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and am having a hard time understanding how a class component's method parameters work. In the code below the handleAddOption method (which helps with adding items upon clicking a button, it's a to-do app) - it takes 'option' as parameter - **but I do not see the arguments supplied in the render method.**

Similarly in the AddOption component the handleAddOption has an argument 'option' - **where is this coming from?**

I'm a newbie to React and to stackoverflow as well, any norms I may not have followed please point out. Thanks for the help.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);   
    this.handleAddOption = this.handleAddOption.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      options: []
    };
  }
  handleAddOption(option) {
    if (!option) {
      return 'Enter valid value to add item';
    } else if (this.state.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
      return 'This option already exists';
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        options: prevState.options.concat(option)
      };
    });
  }
  render() {                                                                                                                  
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.options.map((option) => <p>{option}</p>)}</div>
        <AddOption handleAddOption={this.handleAddOption} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class AddOption extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAddOption2 = this.handleAddOption2.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      error: undefined
    };
  }
  handleAddOption2(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const option = e.target.elements.option.value.trim();
    const error = this.props.handleAddOption(option);
    this.setState(() => {
      return { error };
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAddOption2}>
          <input type="text" name="option" />
          <button>Add Option</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: The submit event of the `<form>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code you provide, `handleAddOption(option)` is called from the `handleAddOption2` function in the `AddOption` component.

```
handleAddOption2(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const option = e.target.elements.option.value.trim();
  const error = this.props.handleAddOption(option);
  this.setState(() => {
    return { error };
  });
}
```

You can see that `option` is `e.target.elements.option.value.trim()`. Now, where does `e` comes from? Tracking the source of the function above, you can see that `handleAddOption2(e)` is a event handler called from here:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleAddOption2}>
  <input type="text" name="option" />
  <button>Add Option</button>
</form>
```

In React, event handlers (e.g. onClick/onSubmit) by default has a default `event` parameter embedded to its handler function. This parameter can be any name (defined by you), and the author of the code you provide named it `e`.

Giving you another example, say you have a `button`:

```
<button onClick={this.sayHello}>
 Click me!
</button>
```

There is already an event param embedded to `sayHello`, but you can choose not to use it.

```
sayHello = () => {
  alert('Hello!');
}
```

Or if you want to use it, I'll name it `event` instead of `e` here:

```
sayHello = (event) => {
  event => alert(event.target.value)
}
```

Or you can choose define the event handler inline like this:

```
<button value="hello!" onClick={event => alert(event.target.value)}>
  Click me!
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! I see now how the option is traveling along the chain of calls.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments are being passed by the submit handler attached to the form.

You provide a function that you want called whenever there is a [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event).  The form will call whatever function you provide with the arguments it usually passes in.

This happens the same way as it happens in plain JS:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("submit 1");
});

const submitHandler = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("submit 2");
};

form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Consider the React example:

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      foo:""
    }
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("MyForm Submit 1");
    this.setState(state => ({
      foo: "foo"
    }));
  }
  render() {
    /*
     onSubmit will always call the function that is provided
     with a submit event argument.
     */
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>{this.state.foo}</div>
        <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

class MyOtherForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      foo:""
    }
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("MyForm Submit 2");
    this.setState(state => ({
      foo: "bar"
    }));
  }
  render() {
    // Here we will pass the argument explicitly
    return (
      <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
        <div>{this.state.foo}</div>
        <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <MyForm/>
      <MyOtherForm/>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>



<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the flow was the other way round.